# Remove object elements from array in javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion, internet-explorer-8, tree

I have a json tree with not determined level, which looks like this:

```
var nodeset = {
    "name" : "FORM",
    "attributes" : {
        "IDFORM" : "59",
        "NOMDOC" : "1",
        "VERSFORM" : "1.01",
        "DATEREPORT" : "10.10.1988"
    },
    "nodes" : [{
            "name" : "PART1",
            "persist" : true,
            "nodes" : [{
                    "name" : "FTYPE",
                    "persist" : true,
                    "value" : "1",
                    "weight" : 1
                }, {
                    "name" : "STARTDATE",
                    "persist" : true,
                    "value" : "01.10.2011",
                    "weight" : 1
                }, {
                    "name" : "ENDDATE",
                    "persist" : true,
                    "value" : "31.12.2011",
                    "weight" : 1
                }
            ],
            "value" : "31.12.2011",
            "weight" : 3
        }, {
            "name" : "PART2",
            "persist" : true,
            "nodes" : [{
                    "name" : "F203",
                    "persist" : true,
                    "value" : 12,
                    "weight" : 1
                }, {
                    "name" : "F204",
                    "persist" : true,
                    "value" : 12,
                    "weight" : 1
                }, {
                    "name" : "STI059DETAIL",
                    "persist" : false,
                    "nodes" : [{
                            "name" : "F1",
                            "persist" : false,
                            "value" : "asd",
                            "weight" : 1
                        }, {
                            "name" : "F2",
                            "persist" : false,
                            "value" : "asd",
                            "weight" : 1
                        }, {
                            "name" : "F3",
                            "persist" : false,
                            "value" : 0,
                            "weight" : 0
                        }, {
                            "name" : "F4",
                            "persist" : false,
                            "value" : 0,
                            "weight" : 0
                        }
                    ],
                    "value" : 0,
                    "weight" : 2
                }, {
                    "name" : "STI059DETAIL",
                    "persist" : false,
                    "nodes" : [{
                            "name" : "F1",
                            "persist" : false,
                            "value" : null,
                            "weight" : 0
                        }, {
                            "name" : "F2",
                            "persist" : false,
                            "value" : null,
                            "weight" : 0
                        }, {
                            "name" : "F3",
                            "persist" : false,
                            "value" : 0,
                            "weight" : 0
                        }, {
                            "name" : "F4",
                            "persist" : false,
                            "value" : 0,
                            "weight" : 0
                        }
                    ],
                    "value" : 0,
                    "weight" : 0
                }, {
                    "name" : "STI059DETAIL",
                    "persist" : false,
                    "nodes" : [{
                            "name" : "F1",
                            "persist" : false,
                            "value" : null,
                            "weight" : 0
                        }, {
                            "name" : "F2",
                            "persist" : false,
                            "value" : null,
                            "weight" : 0
                        }, {
                            "name" : "F3",
                            "persist" : false,
                            "value" : 0,
                            "weight" : 0
                        }, {
                            "name" : "F4",
                            "persist" : false,
                            "value" : 0,
                            "weight" : 0
                        }
                    ],
                    "value" : 0,
                    "weight" : 0
                }
            ],
            "value" : 0,
            "weight" : 4
        }
    ],
    "weight" : 7
};
```

My task is to remove all nodes from it where `weight` is `0` and where `nodes` property exists.

As it is a tree, I've tried to use recursive function like this:

```
function clean(index, owner){
    var node    = owner[index],
        weight  = node.weight;

    delete node.weight;

    if(typeof node.persist != 'undefined'){
        delete node.persist;
    }

    if(!node.nodes)return;

    if(!weight){
        owner.splice(index, 1);
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < node.nodes.length; i++){
        clean(i, node.nodes);
    }
}

for(var i = 0; i < nodeset.nodes.length; i++){
    clean(i, nodeset.nodes);
}
```

But `splice()` somehow, doesn't remove anything from there. I've replaced it with `delete owner[index]`, which causes `null` values on the place of those nodes (which I do not want to see there `:(` ).

**My questions:** Why the `splice()` function not working as I expected (not deleting nodes)? Also, am I took a correct approach? If no, then any other suggestions would be appreciated.

Regards.

Test fiddle [**HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3jLGj/), if it might help somehow.

Comment: When a node weight is 0, the entire subtree rooted at that node needs to go?

Comment: Yes. It need to. Only `value` nodes with `weight` = `0` allowed. Entire subtrees are not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to filter out nodes with 0 weight. First, define a predicate:

```
var keepNode = function(node) {
    return !(node.weight == 0 && node.hasOwnProperty("nodes"));
};
```

Then a function to clean a node of unwanted children and then recurse on the remaining children:

```
function clean(tree) {
    if (tree.nodes) {
         tree.nodes = tree.nodes.filter(keepNode);
         tree.nodes.forEach(clean);
    }
}
```

Finally, process the entire data structure:

```
clean(nodeset);
```

There's almost certainly a more elegant way that recurses as it filters, but this should do the job.

EDIT (because I didn't notice the IE8 tag)

For IE8 (which doesn't support `filter`), you have a couple of choices. You can use the [ES5 shim package](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim) that adds most EcmaScript functions to legacy JS engines. Alternatively, you can use this shim (available further down on the documentation page for `filter` linked above):

```
if (!Array.prototype.filter)
{
  Array.prototype.filter = function(fun /*, thisp*/)
  {
    "use strict";

    if (this == null)
      throw new TypeError();

    var t = Object(this);
    var len = t.length >>> 0;
    if (typeof fun != "function")
      throw new TypeError();

    var res = [];
    var thisp = arguments[1];
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
      if (i in t)
      {
        var val = t[i]; // in case fun mutates this
        if (fun.call(thisp, val, i, t))
          res.push(val);
      }
    }

    return res;
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. IE8 do not like `Array.filter`.

Comment: Still it works under latest Chrome. But not solving issue in IE.

Comment: @CORRUPT - Oops. Didn't notice the IE8 tag. I edited the post.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will reimplement it myself.